# Zip file not created using ZipArchive in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use the ZipArchive class to create a zip file in Laravel.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
```

The following return `true`:

```
$zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
```

So far, so good.

However, the file test.zip isn't created anywhere. I would expect it in the `public` folder, it's not there. I also checked `storage`, and it's not there either.

Strangely, when I try to add a file (which exists) to the zip, there is no error:

```
$zip->addFile($filepath, $filename);
$zip->close();
```

An error only happens when I try to download this archive, which doesn't exist:

```
return response()->download(public_path('test.zip'), 'test.zip');
```

The error, as one might expect, is:

```
The file "/path/to/project/public/test.zip" does not exist
```

Some similar answers state that a missing symlink for the public storage directory is to blame (although I don't see why it should). I have created the symlink to be sure, and the error is still the same.

Comment: why would you expect it to be in 'public'?

Comment: Where else? I've tried doing `$zip->open(public_path('test.zip'))` with the same outcome btw.

Comment: are you creating a zip and making a download response in the same request? and if so, did you close the zip archive?

Comment: Yes I am. Is it a problem to create and download in the same request? And yes I am closing the zip, I forgot to add that bit to the question. I'll add it now.

Comment: and this has nothing to do with a sym link ... the `public` folder isn't a sym link to anything

Comment: See what `var_dump(realpath('test.zip'));` tells you.

Comment: @RoAchterberg That returns `false` for some reason.

Comment: My guess is that `$filepath` does not exist in the location you specified. From the docs: _"Since libzip 1.6.0, a empty file is not a valid archive any longer."_. [A commenter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.close.php#78667) on the `close()` function says: _"Don't forget to check the zip isn't empty, folks - otherwise the zip won't be created at all, and the server will issue no warning!"_.

Comment: Do a `var_dump(realpath($filepath));` and see what it says. Btw you can confirm your assumption of the current working directory by checking `var_dump(getcwd());`.

Comment: also you usually don't have `public` writable

Comment: @RoAchterberg You are correct that `$filepath` was incorrect. Now that that is fixed, there is a new error: `ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please show the code in question.